# Keep value of form after redirect oracle-apex

Tags: forms, oracle-apex

I'm using oracle 4.0 and I'm having some issues with my forms.

I'm having a select list and some textfields. The select list redirects and sets value after choosing an item in it.

When you have selected an item from the list, the textfields will become empty.

How can I save the values from the textfields after redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Change action on select list from `Redirect and Set Value` to `Submit Page`.

Comment: That's not really the option, because redirect resets all the input from other textfields.

Comment: @Elvira Sorry, but I thought you are using `Redirect` now and I had suggested to you *not* to use `Redirect` and use `Submit` instead. Or I understood wrong?